# generating pdf using prawn in background with resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, prawn

I am trying to create a PDF document in the background via Resque background job.

My code for creating the PDF is in a Rails helper method that I want to use in the Resque worker like:

```
class DocumentCreator
  @queue = :document_creator_queue
  require "prawn"

  def self.perform(id)
    @doc = Document.find(id)

    Prawn::Document.generate('test.pdf') do |pdf|
      include ActionView::Helpers::DocumentHelper
      create_pdf(pdf)
    end
  end
end
```

The `create_pdf` method is from the `DocumentHelper` but I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `create_pdf'
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call an instance method (`create_pdf`) from a class method (`self.perform`). Your code would only work if your `DocumentHelper` defined `create_pdf` as a class method:

```
def self.create_pdf
```

If you don't need access to `create_pdf` in your views, you may consider moving it to your `Document` class instead, as an instance method, and then you can do `@doc.create_pdf(pdf)`.

However, if you need access to `create_pdf` in your views as well, you can either put a `module_function :create_pdf` inside your `DocumentHelper` file, or you can dynamically add this in your worker:

```
DocumentHelper.module_eval do
  module_function(:create_pdf)
end
DocumentHelper.create_pdf(pdf)
```

Then you can properly call `DocumentHelper.create_pdf`.

Also, in Rails 3, I think you only need `include DocumentHelper`, rather than `include ActionView::Helpers::DocumentHelper`.