# Generate pdf in the background with Prawn PDF and Resque

Tags: ruby, backgroundworker, resque, prawn

I am trying to generate a PDF with background workers using Prawn PDF and Resque

The code without background workers is:

```
def document
    respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf do
            pdf = ReservationPdf.new(params[:reservation_ids])
            send_data pdf.render, filename: 'reservations.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline', compress: true
        end
    end
end
```

I tried to move the following lines to pdf.rb within app/jobs/ for it to be processed by Resque

```
pdf = ReservationPdf.new(params[:reservation_ids])
send_data pdf.render, filename: 'reservations.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline', compress: true
```

This does not appear to be working properly - I get 'undefined method "send_data"'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not wrong, your `document` method is a controller action, right? So it belongs to a controller.

When you call an action, something should be returned to the requester, in this case is `send_data`

If you try to generate the pdf in background then you should change the response, maybe someting like `head :ok` or just a view telling the user that waits for the pdf.

The next step is generate the pdf in background, you can use this post as example: [generating pdf using prawn in background with resque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525158/generating-pdf-using-prawn-in-background-with-resque)

Then you need to comunicate the user the pdf is ready, one option is send an email, other option is refresh the page until the pdf appears, and other option is that the server push a notification to the browser to get the pdf.